# No qemu-debootstrap in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, lxc

I just installed lxc in Arch Linux, but the `qemu-debootstrap` binary seems missing,

This command `sudo lxc-create -n test -t ubuntu -P /run/shm/1` complains about that.

I couldn't find it with either `pacman` or `yaourt`.

Any ideas how to fix that? I have the `debootstrap` script installed and that works though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debootstrap is in `aur/debootstrap` package. After installation process you will have to make a symlink in `/usr/bin`:

```
cd /usr/bin ; ln -sf debootstrap qemu-debootstrap
```

After that do what ouzmoutous suggests.

Anyway I always advise to use downloaded templates.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents, but combining both answers, wouldn't it be easier to do the following:

`cd /usr/bin ; cp debootstrap qemu-debootstrap`

and then modify the vars? That way, no need to edit the DEF_HTTPS_MIRROR back and forth for debian/ubuntu containers...

To be really thorough and avoid code duplication, it should be simple enough to create a debootcommon script with a run() function and import it inside both:

## debootstrap

```
#!/bin/bash
. /usr/bin/bootcommon

DEF_HTTPS_MIRROR="https://mirrors.kernel.org/debian"

run()
```

## qemu-debootstrap

```
#!/bin/bash
. /usr/bin/bootcommon

DEF_HTTPS_MIRROR="https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu"

run()
```

Comment: Same trick worked on centos6.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/sbin/debootstrap /usr/local/bin/qemu-debootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was quite similar and another error have been printed

```
Failed getting release file https://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/dists/trusty/Release
```

I got a dirty workaround :

Modify the var DEF_HTTPS_MIRROR in /usr/bin/debootstrap to look like this :

```
DEF_HTTPS_MIRROR="https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu"
```

Of course, you'll have to change it when you want to create debian containers.

Comment: this seems totally unrelated to the question...

Comment: It is related. You have to edit debootstrap for ubuntu installation. Ouzmountous show how to do it.